# android asynctask doesnt work

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I use AsyncTask to execute time-consuming operations, the operation scans SD-card and adds all valid photo absolute path to ArrayList container. I put the operation into AsyncTask to execute. The time consuming operation `Utils.getPhotoList();` was placed under `doInbackgroud` method. The return value was assigned to the global variable `list` under `onPostExecute` method. From the log, I know the method was executed and the `list` was assigned a value. But why the global variable `list` under `onStartCommand` method  is always `null`, which confused me a lot. see the code below.

```
 ConcurrentAsyncTask.execute(new PhotoTask());
```

and the complete code is

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  if (isCameraUpload) {
    // execute time-consuming operation
    ConcurrentAsyncTask.execute(new PhotoTask());
  }
  // list is always null    
  if (list != null) {
    notifyUser(photosCount, repoName);
  }
  return START_STICKY;
}
```

and the customized class ConcurrentAsyncTask is.

```
public class ConcurrentAsyncTask {
   public static <T> void execute(AsyncTask<T, ?, ?> task, T...args) {
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
       task.execute(args);
     } else {
       task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, args);
     }
   }

   public static void execute(Runnable runnable) {
     execute(new SimpleAsyncTask(runnable));
   }
   private static class SimpleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     Runnable runnable;
     public SimpleAsyncTask(Runnable runnable) {
       this.runnable = runnable;
     }
     public Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
     try {
       runnable.run();
     } catch(Exception e) {
       // ignore
     }
     return null;
   }
```

}

and the `PhotoTask` class is

```
private class PhotoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<SelectableFile>> {
   @Override
   protected List<SelectableFile> doInBackground(Void... params) {
     Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "doInBackgroud");
     Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "doInBackgroud:pathList.size: " + Utils.getPhotoList().size());
     return Utils.getPhotoList();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(List<SelectableFile> result) {
     Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onPostExecute");
     list = result;
     Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onPostExecute: list.size: " + list.size());
   }
 }
```

any feedback will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it is because you are immediately checking the list variable after starting the AsyncTask which will be null or empty there. You need to put this check in onPostExecute method of AsyncTask and then initiate any other process from there. If your AsyncTask is in another class then your activity then you can use interface to notify the caller class

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela That saves me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve the problem, just divide the operation into parts. the time-consuming operations placed in doInbackground() method, and the result placed in onPostExecute() method.